# Python parse xml file

Tags: python, xml

I need to parse an xml file which method would be best for my case. beautifulsoup4, ElementTree, etc. it's a pretty big file.
I have windows 10 64bit running python 2.7.11 32bit

xml file:
http://pastebin.com/jTDRwCZr

I'm trying to get this output from the xml file it contains different languages using " div xml:lang="English" " for english. any help on how i can use beautifulsoup with lxml to achieve this? thanks for your time.

```
<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1"     xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1#styling">
<head>
<styling>
<style id="1"  tts:textOutline='#000000 2px 2px'  tts:color="white"/>
</styling>
</head>
<body>
<div xml:lang="English">
<p begin="00:00:28.966" end="00:00:31.385" style="1">
text text text...
</p>
</div>
</body>
</tt>
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup with lxml is almost never a bad choice.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are you trying to get just the english language div and ignore any other languages?

Comment: @mhawke yeah that's exactly what i'm trying to accomplish sorry for not explaining that well. trying to get just the english language div and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you link to is not that large that you need to worry about alternative methods of parsing and processing it.

Assuming that you are trying to remove all non-English language `div`s you can do it with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('input.xml') as infile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(infile, 'lxml')
    for e in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'xml:lang': lambda value: value != 'English'}):
        _ = e.extract()

with open('output.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(soup.prettify(soup.original_encoding))
```

In the code above the `soup.find_all()` finds all `div`s that have an `xml:lang` attribute that is a value other than `'English'`. It then removes the matching elements with `extract()`. Finally the resulting document is written out to a new file using the same encoding as the input (otherwise it will default to UTF-8).

Comment: hmm I got strange output file it removed even the english div's

Comment: Sorry I did not explain my last comment well. the code above works great! for some reason however when i tried it on my second xml file. it removed everything. it is the same formatting as the other xml file the only difference being there is even more languages in this one. https://codeshare.io/8KhNE I also want to thank you your explanation on what bs4 does was spot on helped me a lot thank you.

Comment: @xNightmare67x: I tried the above code on your other file and it worked as expected, i.e. it removed all of the `div`s with `xml:lang` not set to `"English"` and left the English one there.

Comment: perhaps I'm doing something wrong? this is the output I get.
https://codeshare.io/neC8J

Comment: @xNightmare67x: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did a few more tests i narrowed it down to the Chinese & Korean div's the characters seem to be causing the problem.
the XML file
https://codeshare.io/8KhNE

Answer (score 0):

Usually DOM approach is quick and easy to use (upto 10 MB). However, if it is the really big xml file (> 50 MB), then XML DOM approach cannot be used since it parses the entire XML object into the memory. It takes upto 3-4 GB of RAM for parsing only upto 100 MBs of data and get significantly slower. 
So the another option would be to do iterative or event based parsing of XML files. 
For iterative parsing, elementTree or lxml approaches can be used. Usually elementTree is quite slow, so I would recommend to use the cElementTree, similar API but implemented in C which is significantly faster than elementTree.
I recently used the elementTree for parsing >100 MB large XML files and it's been working really good for me so far! I'm not sure about lxml.
I would check out online for more information on how to use XML parsing APIs.